# Run a Excel 2007 Workbook project from main project

Tags: c#, excel, desktop-application

This is similar to my last question, however I feel it has to do with another level. Project1 is the MDIForm with a menu item for Reports. One of the reports is an Excel 2007 Workbook project. Both projects are in the same solution.

My question is, how do I run the Excel 2007 Workbook project from the Project1 when t he menu report item is clicked?

Comment: Please don't put "C#" in front of your titles. Just put it in the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for an Excel 2007 Workbook project in VS2008 to process along side a parent application, the workbook project must be built and installed at the desired location of the files, FIRST. Afterward, in the parent application, the Office application (Excel, Word, etc.) needs to be opened and the associated file needs to be opened.